# Under what conditions are the median and average identical?

Tags: statistics, average, means, median

Intuitively, median and average are identical when the distribution of values is symmetrical. But is that a necessary condition? If not, what is?

Comment: Basically the condition is based on the definition of both but it is not very practical : $\int_{-\infty}^m \rho (x)dx=1/2$ and $a=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x\rho (x)dx $. The condition is a=m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, it is not a necessary condition.

Consider for instance the discrete probability distribution $p$ supported on $\{-1,0,\frac{4}{5}\}$ such that
$$
p(-1)=\frac{1}{3}, \quad p(0) = \frac{1}{4}, \quad p\left(\frac{4}{5}\right) = \frac{5}{12}
$$
Then $\mathbb{E}_{X\sim p}[X] = -1\cdot\frac{1}{3}+\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{5}{12} = 0$, and the median of $p$ is also $0$. But the distribution is not symmetric.

As far as I know, there is no simple necessary condition besides what is essentially a restatement of the definitions.